# Is it correct to use "reach out about" in a sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The headline is:

> As mayhem persisted at Kabul’s airport, the Taliban reached out to a
> former Afghan president about a new government.

The way I think it's supossed to be is: "reach out to a former Afghan president" TO something as :

> reach out to a former Afghan president TO TALK about...

Does it makes any sense?

Comment: reach out means to contact.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be "reached out to (someone) [to do something]"

The construction "reach out to (someone) [about something]" is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

"reach out" is no different to any other verb, so it is perfectly OK to add a prepositional phrase "about...", which works as an adverbial to modify the verb.

"reach out" is a relatively new expression: it has only become common since 2000, so usage is not yet set in stone. According to this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reached%20out%20to%20talk%2C%20reached%20out%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), "reached out about.." is used but "reached out to talk about..." is not.

Looking at individual instances of "reached out about...", it seems that the "to..." phrase is optional when an "about..." phrase is used.